# Poistion is fixed but right 0 not working

Tags: html, css

I have `ul` set with `position: fixed` and `right: 0`, but it’s still on the left side.

```css
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar ul {
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  right: 0;
}

#navbar ul li {
  right: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 105px;
  color: rgb(252, 227, 0);
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>Menu</a></li>
    <li><a><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>Merchandise</a></li>
    <li><a><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>About band</a></li>
    <li><a><i class="fas fa-music"></i>Listen now...</a>
      <ul>
        <li>self titled</li>
        <li>regional at best</li>
        <li>vessel</li>
        <li>blurryface</li>
        <li>trench</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `right` and `position` aren't applied to the same element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pick an element that takes both selectors (position and right)..

```
#navbar ul{
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```